# duda con ficheros y estructuras en c++

Tags: c++

Hola no me aclaro con este proyecto ya que no se como asociar los datos del fichero con la estructura y viceversa en general voy bastante perdido agradeceria ayuda ;)

El programa a realizar nos debe permitir gestionar a los alumnos y además calcular algunas estadísticas relacionadas con los datos disponibles. Para ello se van a establecer una serie de requisitos mínimos que el programa debe satisfacer El programa comenzará cargando en memoria dentro de un vector los datos de todos los
alumnos que están almacenados en el fichero de texto (alumnos.txt). Cada elemento de
dicho vector será un registro donde se recoge toda la información relativa a un estudiante.

Basicamente no se como utilizar los datos que tengo en el fichero para usarlo en el programa en este caso yo en el fichero tengo datos de alumnos de la siguiente manera
nombre y apellidos
nota edad sexo
no se como coger esos datos del fichero y usarlos en el programa para poder modificar los datos del fichero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct alumnos {
    string DNI;
    string nombre;
    float  nota;
    int    edad;
    char   sexo;
};

void menu();
void consultas();
void insertaralumno();
void eliminar();
void estadisticas();

int main() {
    typedef alumnos vector[100];
    alumnos         alumno;
    alumno.nombre;

    menu();

    return 0;
}

void menu() {
    ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("alumnos.txt", ios::app);
    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    string nombre;
    int    eleccion;

    cout << "Introduzca su nombre: " << endl;
    cin >> nombre;
    do {
        cout << "¡Hola! " << nombre
             << " seleccione lo que desee hacer: " << endl;
        cout << "1.- Consultas" << endl;
        cout << "2.- Insertar" << endl;
        cout << "3.- Eliminar" << endl;
        cout << "4.- Estadisticas" << endl;
        cout << "5.- Salir" << endl;
        cin >> eleccion;

        switch (eleccion) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Ha elegido usted Consultas" << endl;
            consultas();

            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Ha elegido usted Insertar" << endl;

            insertaralumno();

            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Ha elegido usted Eliminar" << endl;
            eliminar();

            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Ha elegido usted Estadisticas" << endl;
            estadisticas();

            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Ha elegido usted Salir" << endl;

            break;

        default:
            cout << "Elija una opción válida (1-5)" << endl;
        }

    } while (eleccion > 5);
}

void consultas() {
    int      eleccion;
    int      dni;
    ifstream archivo;
    archivo.open("alumnos.txt", ios::app);

    string linea;
    cout << "Elija lo que desea consultar: " << endl;
    cout << "1.-Buscar un alumno por DNI" << endl;
    cout << "2.-Visualizar los datos de todos los alumnos" << endl;
    cin >> eleccion;
    do {
        switch (eleccion) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Introduzca el DNI a buscar: " << endl;
            cin >> dni;

            break;
        case 2:
            ifstream archivo;
            string   texto;
            archivo.open("alumnos.txt", ios::in);
            while (!archivo.eof()) {
                getline(archivo, texto);
                cout << texto << endl;
            }
            archivo.close();

            break;
        }
    } while (eleccion > 2);
}
void insertaralumno() {}

void eliminar() {}

void estadisticas() {
    int opcion;
    do {
        cout << "Elija entre las opciones: " << endl;
        cout << "1.-Calcular la media de edad. " << endl;
        cout << "2.-Calcular el porcentaje de mujeres y hombres. " << endl;
        cout << "3.-Calcular el porcentaje de estudiantes aprobados. " << endl;
        cin >> opcion;
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        default:
            cout << "Elija una opción válida (1-3)" << endl;
        }

    } while (opcion > 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo habitual para la tarea que describes es sobrecargar los operadores de lectura desde flujo de datos (`>>`) y escritura en flujo de datos (`<<`). Por ejemplo:

```
// Escribir en flujo de datos
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const alumno &a)
{
    return o << a.DNI << '\n'
             << a.nombre << '\n'
             << a.nota << '\n'
             << a.edad << '\n'
             << a.sexo << '\n';
}
// Leer desde flujo de datos
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, alumno &a)
{
    i >> a.DNI;
    i >> a.nombre;
    i >> a.nota;
    i >> a.edad;
    i >> a.sexo;
    return i;
}
```

Fíjate que he cambiado el nombre de la estructura `alumos` a `alumno` pues no tiene sentido que la estructura tenga nombre plural si almacena un solo alumno.

Teniendo esos operadores sobrecargados, la escritura en archivo es tan sencilla como esto:

```
alumno a1{"12345A", "Pepe", 10.f, 10, 'h'};
alumno a2{"67890B", "Pepa", 10.f, 10, 'm'};

if (std::ofstream o{"datos.txt"})
    o << a1 << a2;
```

Y la lectura es igualmente sencilla:

```
if (std::ifstream i{"datos.txt"})
{
    alumno temp;
    i >> temp;
    std::cout << "Leido: " << temp;
    i >> temp;
    std::cout << "Leido: " << temp;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJda4MwFH1ufsXFQW3BtbX7rkXY2B4GZewH7CXV2GZoIjFCQfrb3Y1Rh3ZPe4k5J/cm55xrlOfXUUrFoa6vuIjSMmaw5bLQitEsJL9cckkhw8UhJAQ3ZaSBpmUmJFRkUuh4s7HH8PrxHgwZIbO9YkgmqaQaEGuKiAvcA7CYxoiiI1WICnaSATkHhCyX8FZEiu@5AiYgSctvCSgjploWpLm/lQ1TmTOFtILtdjY68SCSoujFTumcoGDFdKkESGwAukDJZuN@CZdMJg1lNV@ymo45o3/MGRcdh26Mlx1jCuUX6OAvK/zCShjOhifcG5ngWGPVBz3os@6xzdqiNusW2ay7LLgRSsxQMsrFrHmhfY/6leOvb27vnh0PnE@WM/z6q0ViVg/co4sD64vXlXP/8Pi0emmL6bA4M8WoIYF2VO2fBrJymkAW@qSd8xyztOPxm3U9aOJdEx83oepOiWZZjrqs3Q407ZEstbnV2TEeyw04BvyvHDPrElxhgnX9Aw)</kbd>.